# Make Triangle shape over a div

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Can someone tell me how I can present my users with a triangle over the background image. I want to make a triangular UI. For that I'm masking two images(one background.jpg and masking image, triangle.png). I'm using this new image in my a div's background. I have accomplished this using [MaskImage](http://verens.com/2011/08/25/jquery-maskimage-plugin/).

[image: Resulting image]

But the problem is that the size of my background image changes but the size of triangle.png is fixed. I have also tried using linear-gradient, css property. but it is not working in IE. So is there any plugin which mask two images irrespective of there sizes. or any other optimal way to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If using html5, I would go for canvas and create a triangle shape as a mask to be able to adjust its size according to the image sizes ratio `:/` some js libraries might do that for you ...

Comment: yes it is very easy that way but I'm not using HTML5. so any other suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to overlay two masking triangles using `:before` and `:after` in CSS and create triangles using uneven border properties like http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/A9Zbj/11/ (Yay!)